# Excel VBA, execute Macro on selected cell

Tags: vba, excel

My problem is that I need to execute a Macro only on the marked cell.

The Macro needs to do the following:

Selected cell is formated always for example as 20*20*20 always 3 numbers.

It should copy this text add a " =  " before the numbers and output it on another column.

The Code I got until now is:

```
Sub First()
'
' First Makro
'

'
    Selection.Copy
    Range("G11").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=20*20*20"
    Range("G12").Select
End Sub
```

I have got this code with the record Macro function

Thanks very much

Comment: Where are you copying and where are you pasting? Your question is not clear. Please exactly explain what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @SiddharthRout hi Sir 

yeah I wanted to be able to select the cell by hand which gets copied to the same row but 2 columns further

Comment: So you are copying from "E11" in the above code?

Comment: If yes then see the code that I posted below. You may have to refresh the page to see it

Comment: @SiddharthRout exactly but i need to be able to select it by hand because sometimes it's for example E17

sometimes e33 

and output always need's to be G Column in the Same Row

Answer (score 1):

> @SiddharthRout exactly but i need to be able to select it by hand because sometimes it's for example E17 sometimes e33 and output always need's to be G Column in the Same Row

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    '~~> Replace Sheet1 with the relevant sheet name
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

     '~~> Check if what the user selected is a valid range
    If TypeName(Selection) <> "Range" Then
        MsgBox "Select a range first."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    '~~> Check if the user has selected a single cell
    If Selection.Cells.Count > 1 Then
        MsgBox "Please select a single cell"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ws.Range("G" & Selection.Row).Formula = "=" & Selection.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm getting a runtime error when I execute this script

Comment: Thanks for your help but I'm getting this error when I execute the macro.

Runtime Error 9 and Bound out of Array


http://imgur.com/a/37f39

Comment: When you click on deug, which line does it take you to?

Comment: I'm getting to the line where I need to input my Map name

http://imgur.com/a/zQjkt

Comment: Is that the name of the current worksheet? Also ensure that the sheet is active